# JQuery Plugin Integration with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using jquery notification plugin, I tried to call the function of this plugin in angular controller shown in the below code, but always gives an exception that the method I'm calling isn't defined. I think the problem comes from the way I call this function; So does anyone know a right way for calling it ?!

```js
 $scope.AddLayout = function () {
        LayoutApi.AddLayout(angular.toJson($scope.Layout)).success(function () {   
            $.sticky("Layout Saved Successfully", {
                stickyClass: 'success'
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the char **'$'** by **'jQuery'**:

```
jQuery.sticky("Layout Saved Successfully", {
  stickyClass: 'success'
});
```

Comment: @HanaYehia Are you sure that the jQuery lib is loaded? What happens if you open the browser console and type jQuery on it?

Comment: yes it's loaded. The plugin in a separate file and it's loaded too.

Comment: Maybe your code is been executed before the DOM is ready. Try wrapping it inside this: jQuery(function(){...});

Comment: I solved it this way          
   angular.element().sticky("Layout Saved Successfully", {
                stickyClass: 'success'
            });